# "The transaction has aborted" exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, transactionscope, sqlfilestream

I have this code to write an image into `SqlFileStream`,

```
string strFileId;
using (var oTransaction = new TransactionScope()) {    
    var oSqlParameter = new SqlParameter[5];
    oSqlParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@FileName", imageName);
    oSqlParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@Description", "Description");
    oSqlParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@MimeType", mimeType);
    oSqlParameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@Size", size);
    oSqlParameter[4] = new SqlParameter("@FileObjectsId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

    DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(ConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SPInsImage", oSqlParameter);

    strFileId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FileObjectsId"].ToString();
    string strSqlPath = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString();
    var bytArrContext = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column2"];

    var fileStream = new SqlFileStream(strSqlPath, bytArrContext, FileAccess.Write);
    fileStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
    oTransaction.Complete();
}// throw an TransactionAbortedException
return strFileId;
```

Other blogs suggested that it's timeout issue and I've tried to change the transaction timeout but it didn't work.

**I've tried to use the same code on another server and it's working fine.**
I'm not facing any problem with the database connection, but after writing on `SqlFileStream` context after `oTransaction.Complete()` line when the `using` brackets closed it throws an *TransactionAbortedException* with this message:

> "An uncommittable transaction was detected at the beginning of the
>   batch. The transaction was rolled back. This was caused by an error
>   that occurred during the processing of a FILESTREAM request in the
>   context of this transaction."